# RichTextBox - how to pass markup codes

Tags: wpf, richtextbox

I'm using the `RichTextBox` to display some readonly text that I have to markup on the fly. 
How can I pass markup codes in text to have it rendered by the `RichTextBox` control?

For example, I'd like to pass `this is \cf6 sample \cf1 text` to the richtextbox for it to render.

Right now, I build a `FlowDocument` and add the text value to a run object, but the text gets rendered literally.

```
RichTextBox fieldLabel = new RichTextBox();

FlowDocument flowDoc = new FlowDocument();
Paragraph myPara = new Paragraph();
Run myRun = new Run(content);

myPara.Inlines.Add(myRun);
flowDoc.Blocks.Add(myPara);
fieldLabel.Document = flowDoc;
```

I want to see the value in red, but I see the markup instead.

Thanks in advance for any input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant assign RTF text just like that. You need to get that text into a stream and then pass that stream to the RichTextBox.Selection.Load() method. e.g.

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(UTF8Encoding.Default.GetBytes(yourRTFText));
fieldLabel.Selection.Load(stream, DataFormats.Rtf);
```

Comment: Are you sure about that?  You might want to check the documentation.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.aspx

Comment: Yes. See this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.textrange.load.aspx

Comment: Here's a sample that works using the same code pasted above. 

`private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string yourRTFText = @"{\rtf1\ansi{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss Helvetica;}\f0\pard
This is some {\b bold} text.\par
}";
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(UTF8Encoding.Default.GetBytes(yourRTFText));
            richTextBox1.Selection.Load(stream, DataFormats.Rtf);
        }`

Comment: I did not contend you can't bind to memory steam.  You stated "cant assign RTF text just like that" and that is the basis of my comment.   If a memory stream is the only way to embed control then you were not clear on that.

Comment: Ok, tx.. IUnknown, that works.  But after this discussion i think i'd prefer to create the flowdocument in the rules logic, then dump the xaml as a string , which i will then have the rendering engine load that xaml string back into a flowdocument, and assign that to the rtfcontrol.  A couple of good posts show how that is done.

Comment: It'd be great if you appended those links to the question so that subsequent searchers would benefit. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply to the paragraph

```
// Create a FlowDocument to contain content for the RichTextBox.
FlowDocument myFlowDoc = new FlowDocument();

// Add paragraphs to the FlowDocument.
myFlowDoc.Background = Brushes.LightBlue;
myFlowDoc.Foreground = Brushes.DarkRed;
myFlowDoc.Typography.Capitals = FontCapitals.SmallCaps;
myFlowDoc.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run("Paragraph 1")));
Paragraph p = new Paragraph(new Run("Paragraph 2"));
p.Foreground = Brushes.Black;
myFlowDoc.Blocks.Add(p);
myFlowDoc.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run("Paragraph 3")));
RichTextBox myRichTextBox = new RichTextBox();

// Add initial content to the RichTextBox.
myRichTextBox.Document = myFlowDoc;
```

Comment: tx, problem,the creation of the flow document is separate from the data rules.Essentially one area builds the text,and the engine is taking the content 'knowing' its rtf formatted and placing it into a document so the rtf box can read it.So this doesn't really work for me, or i would have done this. although, i suppose it may be an option that i create a flowdocument xml that i send to the engine, and let the engine read the document as the content. But is there a way like i mention with direct markup?  I remember using rtf control in VB6 that allowed input of either plain text or rtf text.

Comment: OK I get it.  Your example implies you can manipulate the FlowDoc.  I remember somehow dealing with this where I had to declare the input as XML.  Did you try the answer from iUnknown?